# Varnish + Apache + WordPress redirects to port 8080 instead of serving at port 80

Tags: wordpress, apache, vagrant, lamp, varnish

I've setup a WordPress site on a Vagrant VM, which is running on Apache at port `8080`. I can visit the site using my VM IP `http://192.168.33.10:8080/`.

Then I've Varnish setup at port `80` so visiting `http://192.168.33.10` should serve the cached version of the WP site which is running on port `8080`.

But every time I try to reach this address `http://192.168.33.10`, it redirects to `http://192.168.33.10:8080/`.
This is only happening when I'm trying to serve a WordPress site/page. Because keeping the same settings, I've placed an `apache-index.html` file inside `/var/www/html/` and visiting `http://192.168.33.10/apache-index.html` serves the varnish cached version without any problem. The redirects only occur when trying to visit any WordPress page.

Here are my configurations:

#### Apache

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Apache host root folder is `/var/www/html/`.

#### Varnish

`/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

`/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

```
backend default { 
    .host = "127.0.0.1"; 
    .port = "8080"; 
}
```

I've tried this on an AWS VM too and done lot's of research but got the same result. I hope someone can help me to get rid of this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that wordpress is redirecting you. Can you test a curl request from the instance to 127.0.0.1:8080 and check the headers for redirect?

Comment: Yes, it's WordPress which making the redirect issue. I've changed the `siteurl` and `home` to `http://192.168.33.10` from the back-end and it's working fine now. Don't know if this is the proper solution.

Comment: I think it's the right thing to do. Just be aware that by doing this you won't be able to reach your site on 192.168.33.10:8080. If you want to do it, you'll have to make wordpress "multisite" https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm unable to reach the site at 8080. But that's practically ok for me.
Thanks for your comment.